# Gnome DE bootloader, how to remove

Tags: unity, grub2, gnome, bootloader

I used to have Gnome DE while using 14.04 which came with the black Gnome Bootloader + loading screen. Now I upgraded to 16.04, removed Gnome DE and using Unity alone. I still have Gnome Flashback installed on this PC.

Is there any chance, I can get rid of this black bootloader and use Ubuntu default. Is yes, which packages should I remove using Synaptic, and which to add ? Thanks.